# Vim code completion menu

Tags: vim, autocomplete

Is there a way to leave code completion menu without selecting any option? (after pressing `<C-x><C-o>`)

I am looking for something equivalent for pressing `<Esc>` in VisualStudio Intellisense menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. See [docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#complete_CTRL-E) for further information.

Comment: And if you want to use `<Esc>` like those IDEs, you can try this mapping, however I've only tested the basic case.  `:inoremap <expr> <esc> pumvisible() ? '<C-e>' : '<Esc>'`

Comment: @RandyMorris: This solution tampers with arrow-key navigation in insert mode as arrows begin with Esc.